# Who wrote the music for the first Star Wars movie bar scene?

Tags: star-wars

Just wondering. It was a little funky and strange. (It was supposed to be) but it also worked. Someone had to write it. I couldn't tell from the credits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The songs in question, "Cantina Band 1 & 2," were written by John Williams and performed by the London Symphony Orchestra.
Williams was the composer for all the [tracks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(soundtrack)) in the movie.

Comment: You know I think you are right

Comment: [Quora has an answer that quotes sleeve notes from the soundtrack albums](https://www.quora.com/Did-John-Williams-create-the-Cantina-Song-in-Star-Wars/answer/Alex-Diaz-Granados) and there is apparently more to say on this subject.

Comment: Quora, I'll see if I can find those notes on line and check em out

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the one you are looking for:

This is by the artists: **[Figrin D'an and the Modal Nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figrin_D%27an_and_the_Modal_Nodes)**

Comment: Pretty sure Figrin D'an and the Modal Nodes is fictional ;)

Comment: Varun, good that was quick. How did you do that. I remember I had a very good friend who was a very famous musician who also liked his whisky. The bar scene was one of his favorites and he laughed and laughed

Comment: I think sudhanva's answer is right

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: The answer to 'who wrote the music for...' is usually John Williams!

Comment: A disco version by Meco "Star Wars Theme/ Cantina Band" made it to #1 in Billboard Hot 100 list for two weeks in October 1977.

Comment: @sudhanva if you read the first sentence in the linked Wiki page, it says they are fictional...

Comment: @sudhanva there are plenty of fictional/ virtual artists and their work are pretty famous too, like **[Gorillaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorillaz)**. Although the music is generally made by someone real, the artists are still virtual or non-existent.

Comment: Well I love all th answeres to this question and consider all of them put together to be the real answer. Thanks all that was fun

Comment: And let's not forget the country music version played in the film Paul...

Answer (score 2):

In-Universe we now have canon confirmation from the short story [Not For Nothing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Not_for_Nothing) that the music was **an original composition  by Bith composer and bandleader [Figrin D’an](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Figrin_D%27an)** and played in the cantina by his band, [Figrin D’an and the Modal Nodes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Figrin_D%27an_and_the_Modal_Nodes).

> *The reason should be obvious: Figrin D’an is the best composer and
>   bandleader you will ever find this side of the galaxy. We knew that if
>   we left, we’d never be able to find another leader quite like him.
>   When we’re getting thrown into shackles or washing sand out of our
>   eyes, it’s hard to appreciate him. When we’re playing, nothing in all
>   the worlds is better.*
>
> ...
>
> ***As we played another one of D’an’s newest songs*** (captivity had been
>   strangely inspirational to him, I have to admit), I thought about
>   those droids and the stormtroopers that searched for them. I thought
>   about a possible reward. And then I decided that if that human could
>   do us a favor without us knowing him at all, we could do those other
>   humans a favor and not report them. We were safe now, and could keep
>   playing.
>
> <sub><sup>[From a Certain Point of View:](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/From_a_Certain_Point_of_View) [Not for Nothing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Not_for_Nothing)</sup></sub>